# How to show $(\mathbb{Z},+)=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, functions

$a\circ b=a+b-1$

$a+b=a+b$  (normal addition)

Both $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},\circ)$ are groups.

I need to show surjectivity of $f:(\mathbb{Z},\circ)\to (\mathbb{Z},+), x\mapsto x-1$.

But for that, I have to show that any $y\in (\mathbb{Z},+)$ has a $x\in (\mathbb{Z},\circ)$ with $f(x)=y$.

$f(y+1)=(y+1)-1=y$

shows that, **but only if $x=(y+1)$ is element of $(\mathbb{Z},\circ)$.**

How do I do that?

Comment: Are $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}, \circ)$ groups?

Comment: @wgrenard yes, and + is the nomal addition

Comment: The question is confusing in its current form. Probably you should show that  $f(x\circ y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Instead, you are asking why $y+1$ is an integer, if $y$ is an integer??

Comment: @PeterFranek no, that y+1 is an integer if y is one, that's clear. But how i do i know that y is in fact an integer?

Comment: I though that everywthing is about integers, or what is $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: ok, so $y\in (\mathbb{Z},+)$ implies that it is an integer? (yes i mean ...-1,0,1,2... with Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of a group $(G, \cdot)$ are the elements of the underlying set $G$. It is not standard to write something like $g \in (G,\cdot)$. Rather, you would write $g \in G$.

Thus, $x$ and $y$ in your proof are in fact elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ah ok, then it was only a misconception of me. But is $f:(\mathbb{Z},\circ)\to (\mathbb{Z},+), x\mapsto x-1$ perfectly fine? or is $f:Z\to Z$ better?

Comment: In this specific case I would say it's better to write $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ because you are just trying to prove surjectivity, and this is a property which has nothing to do with the group structure. It only has to do with the function on the underlying set, $\mathbb{Z}$. If you were, instead, talking about $f$ as a group homomorphism (which it actually is), you may want to use the other notation to explicitly specify what binary operations are preserved by the homomorphism.